# how can I post checkbox form elements to a PHP script?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am trying to submit a form with checkbox elements inside a datatables.net table.

This example illustrates what I want to do: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/form.html

But instead of the alert message, I want the values to be posted (using form action to a PHP script)

I added this line...

```
<form id="form" action="test.php" method="post">
```

and removed the alert...

```
alert( "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+sData );
```

But my PHP script see only the checkbox values posted on the current 'page' using the pager buttons of datatables.net. Leave the alert line in the script, I do see all the correct checkbox values.

How can I remove the alert and have the serialized data posted to my test.php script?

Answer (score 0):

jquery:

```
$('#submit_to_test').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "test.php",
  data: $('#form').serialize(),
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
  });
});
```

In the html add a button with an id, for example:

```
<button id="submit_to_test">Submit</button>
```

Comment: thanks, but I could not get this solution to work either. See me test: http://www.blankinside.co.uk/solution2.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have removed **return false;** below the **alert( "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+sData );**

or

You can also remove the whole form submit function as displayed below because it does not needed anymore

```
    $('#form').submit( function() {
    var sData = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
    alert( "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+sData );
    return false;
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Removing the 'return false' does not fix the problem. See my example: http://www.blankinside.co.uk/solution1.php - try selecting a check box from multiple 'pages' of the table. The $_POST array is output at the top of the page after pressing submit.

Comment: From the preamble on the example: "The trick here is that DataTables does not include the DOM elements which are not currently being displayed, therefore you need to add a submit event handler to gather together all of the input elements from the table, and then use the handy jQuery serialize() function to string together the data."

So, maybe my question should be how do I post the variable sData from

`var sData = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();`

to my PHP script using line using...
    
`<form id="form" action="<?PHP echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolve this early today, and in search for something else I found you question, here is my solution

// THIS WILL SELECT ALL CHECKBOX OR DESELECT

// You must create an hidden input with ID "ib_seleccionar_todos" for this example for the "select all" work
and another input named "is_seleccionados" for send to the other php page

// NOTE: here the object datatable is named "tbl_buscar_exalumnos_Table" change this for the one you use

```
$('#lnk_opt_seleccionar_todos').click( function(event){
    if ( $("#ib_seleccionar_todos").val() == 0 ){
        $(':input:checkbox.chk_seleccionado', tbl_buscar_exalumnos_Table.fnGetNodes()).attr("checked", "checked");
        $("#ib_seleccionar_todos").val(1);
    } else {
        $(':input:checkbox.chk_seleccionado', tbl_buscar_exalumnos_Table.fnGetNodes()).removeAttr("checked");
        $("#ib_seleccionar_todos").val(0);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});

$("#btn_agregar_mailing").click( function(){            
     $("#frm_mailing").submit(); 
});

$('#frm_mailing').submit( function() {
    var sData = $('input', tbl_buscar_exalumnos_Table.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
    $('#is_seleccionados').val(sData);
});
```

THAT, will make a SERIALIZE array.
something like this

```
 [is_seleccionados] => chk_seleccionado%5B%5D=9755396&chk_seleccionado%5B%5D=9907119&chk_seleccionado%5B%5D=12955872&chk_seleccionado%5B%5D=13023863
```

the one I explode in the recieving page like this

```
$is_seleccionados  = $_POST["is_seleccionados"];
$ia_arma_selecciondos = explode("&", $is_seleccionados );

    foreach( $ia_arma_selecciondos  as $key => $value ){
        $ia_rut_selecc = explode("=", $value );
        $ia_seleccionado[] = $ia_rut_selecc[1];
    }

    $ia_seleccionado = array_values( array_unique($ia_seleccionado) );
    // $ia_seleccionado = array_values($ia_seleccionado);
    foreach( $ia_seleccionado  as $key => $ii_rut_value ){
       //DO SOMETHING with $key or $ii_rut_value
    }
```

HOPE WORK. 
Ricardo Muñoz
Viva Chile!